# Converting nsarray to nsdata to nsstring to use in label

Tags: nsstring, nsdata, nskeyedarchiver

Help from the more experienced Obj C coders will be greatly appreciated as I've been stuck on this for a few days, and I believe the code is 'close'.

I'm creating a list of names from the users contacts, then I pass this list back to a label. My problem (I think) is getting from the NSData format I'm using to archive the list with NSKeyedArchiver into an NSString. I've read everything I can find, but I suspect my being a NOOB is holding me back from deciphering some other example.

Here is the part of my *.m file where I create a list of persons into an array called "_objects", then I archive the "_objects" (NSKeyArchiver) making an NSData (data) which I then try to create a NSString (guestListString) from. It seems to all go well, except the "guestListString" has a bunch of extra gobblygook characters (yeah, a high tech term) included all around my list of person names. I've tried other formats, but they either return (null) or a bunch of foriegn looking characters. I suspect I've not learned some step I need to insert to get rid of these 'gobbly gook' characters around my list of comma separated names.

Here is the code:

```
// now grab the 'person' property from the Addressbook, pass it as a string back to 'tableview cell', inserting it at 'row 0' and update display
- (void)displayPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {

    if (!_objects) {
        _objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    } 

    NSString *selectedPerson = (__bridge NSString *)ABRecordCopyCompositeName(person);
    //NSString *firstname =(__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person,kABPersonFirstNameProperty); 
    //NSString *lastname =(__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person,kABPersonLastNameProperty);
#ifdef DEBUG
    NSLog(@"displayPerson insertRowsAtIndexPath selectedPerson = "@"%@",selectedPerson); // shows last added name
#endif
    [_objects insertObject:selectedPerson atIndex:0];
    //[_objects insertObject:firstname atIndex:0];
    //[_objects insertObject:lastname atIndex:0];
#ifdef DEBUG
    NSLog(@"displayPerson insertRowsAtIndexPath _objects = "@"%@",_objects); // shows 'list' of all names currently in list
    //NSLog(@"displayPerson insertRowsAtIndexPath stringWithFormat _objects = "@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_objects]);
#endif
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];    
    //
    // (Code to Archive an array) Given that "_objects" contains an array of 'selectedPerson' objects
    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:_objects];
    // Now save to NSUser defaults
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:@"_objects"];
    // Now let's see what is in 'data'
    NSLog(@"archive of 'data' from key _objects = "@"%@",data); // shows long list of 8 bit numbers
    //
    // (Code to unarchive an array) Now to unarchive: 
    // I'm doing this code example here just so I understand unarchive procedure; not needed in actual app code
    NSData *_objectsData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"_objects"];
    NSArray *backIntoArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:_objectsData];
    //
    // Now lets see what is in "backIntoArray"
    NSLog(@"unarchive of _objectsData = "@"%@",_objectsData); // shows long list of 8 bit numbers
    NSLog(@"unarchive of NSArray to backIntoArray = "@"%@",backIntoArray); // shows 'list' of all names currently in list
    //
    // Now convert NSData (data) to NSString so I can pass it to other elecments like 'labels'
    //NSString *guestListString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]; // this is equivalent code to next two lines
    NSString *guestListString;
    guestListString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]; // returns extra characters around list of names instead of list of names ???
    // other potential format options that could exist
    //guestListString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSNEXTSTEPStringEncoding]; // shows 
    //guestListString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSJapaneseEUCStringEncoding]; // shows 
    //guestListString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSNEXTSTEPStringEncoding]; // shows 
    //guestListString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; // returns (null) ???
    //guestListString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding]; // shows 
    //guestListString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSSymbolStringEncoding]; // returns (null) ??? 
    //guestListString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding]; // returns (null) ??? 
    //guestListString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSShiftJISStringEncoding]; // shows 
    //guestListString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSISOLatin2StringEncoding]; // shows 
    //guestListString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding]; // returns string of japanese looking characters??? 
    //guestListString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding]; // shows 
    //guestListString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding]; // shows 
    //guestListString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSWindowsCP1253StringEncoding]; // shows 
    //guestListString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSWindowsCP1254StringEncoding]; // shows 
    //guestListString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSWindowsCP1250StringEncoding]; // returns (null) ??? 
    //guestListString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSISO2022JPStringEncoding]; // shows 
    //guestListString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding]; // shows 
    //guestListString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding]; // returns string of japanese looking characters??? 
    //guestListString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding]; // shows 
    //guestListString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding]; // returns string of japanese looking characters??? 
    //guestListString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF32StringEncoding]; // returns (null) ??? 
    //guestListString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding]; // returns (null) ??? 
    //guestListString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding]; // returns (null) ??? 
    //guestListString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSProprietaryStringEncoding]; // shows 
    //
    // show me what is stored in NSString 'guestListString' 
    NSLog(@"displayPerson NSString conversion of 'data' to 'guestListString' = "@"%@",guestListString); // 
    //
    // Pass the required text back to 'guestsListLabel.text' on ViewController screen
    //((InitialViewController *)self.presentingViewController).guestListLabel.text=selectedPerson; // This WORKS passing back the last selectedPerson 1 name
    ((InitialViewController *)self.presentingViewController).guestListLabel.text=guestListString; // Not working yet; trying to pass back full list of names
    //
    // add code here to handle saving of guestlist before leavig this 'insertRowsAtIndexPath' section
    // Archiving is simple, using the following code:
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    // This next line archives objects correctly so they can be reloaded later and be editable (mutable) 
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:_objects] forKey:@"guestListTable"];
    // This next line writes the value loaded into 'guestListLabel.text' into variable 'kGuestListText' which is used in InitialViewController to display in all 3 field types
    [userDefaults setValue:((InitialViewController *)self.presentingViewController).guestListLabel.text forKey:kGuestsListText];
    // update with all userDefaults variables
    [userDefaults synchronize];
    //
}
```

Comment: what do you mean with **past it other elements like labels**? It appears that you are trying to convert an NSData of your _object into an NSString